# Multiply numbers to variable

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a simple lottery system. I've come to the part where I need to find out how much money in total have been won at the draw.

My idea is to make a variable called `won = 0` and multiply the prize to the variable each time it finds a winner. It does not seem to want to multiply to the variable `won`.

Why won't it add to the variable `won`? And is there an easier way to do this? Maybe with a method?

- `bought[i].lotterynumber` is the array where it finds the lotterynumber
- `draw[x][0]` is the winner numbers.

.

```
won = 0

for x in 0..4
  for i in 0..11
    if bought[i].lotterynumber == draw[x][0] 

      if x == 0 
        won += 4000000
      else

      end

      if x == 1 
        won += 1250000
      else

      end

      if x == 2 

        won += 500000

      else

      end

      if x == 3 
        won += 200000
      else

      end

      if x == 4 or 5 
        won += 200000
      else

      end
    end
  end
end

puts won.to_s
```

Comment: please show us what the draw-array and bought-array looks like.

Comment: What is `0..4` and `0..11`? Is that the entire arrays or just a just a part of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All if statements should just be a case-statement

```
won += case x
  when 0
    4000000
  when 1
    1250000
  when 2
    500000
  when 3,4,5
    200000
  else
    0
end
```

Comment: hmm still wont multiply the number into won variable

Comment: Yes sorry my answer is only to format the code better, the flawed logic is hard to spot if we do not get more info about the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify an `else` caluse(I noticed you've added empty elses for all ifs). This is valid ruby:

```
    if x == 0 
        won += 4000000
    end
```

However this will not do what you expect:

```
    if x == 4 or 5 
        won += 200000
    else
```

As it will always evaluate to true. Fix the statement to:

```
    if x == 4 or x == 5 
        won += 200000
    else
```